# How to highlight div when id is given in url

Tags: html, css, highlight

How to highlight div when it is shown using `id`.

As Stackoverflow has this:

try going to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47110005/how-to-highlight-div-when-id-is-given-in-url#comment81170214_47110005), it will highlight the div.

How to do that?

Comment: This div is highlighted when you click the link mentioned in the question! How to do thist?

Comment: @TemaniAfif I searched a lot for this, but I didn't get anything related to this.

Comment: you simply need to understand what's happening an reproduce it. Highlight have no meaning in HTML/CSS. what is done is simply some animation when you go to a specific block, If you know some JS/CSS you can do it

Comment: @TemaniAfif Any hint.... for working code

Comment: check this link https://css-tricks.com/on-target/ .. i did a simple google search and got it

Comment: @NIKHILAWARI: look into the source code, both CSS and JS are visible.

Comment: It's absolutely necessary to learn, how to research for solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a href="#idOfTag">Jump</a>
<p id="idOfTag">Your content goes here</p>
```

You can jump to something just by appending an `#divid` to the end of the URL.
To highlight it you have to use CSS Animations or JS/jQuery.

UPDATE:
Here is a working example including code from Google: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xfjrh

In this case the CSS :target-method is used. It is called when jumping to an anchor like in the example above.

Comment: So, how to highlight it, I know use of `#`

Comment: Thanks it is working, but a problem it works at `www.domain.com/index.php#target` and not on `www.domain.com/#target`, why so?

Comment: Hmm, appereantly it's not forwarding that parameter. You may have to use .htacess there. You should create a new Questions for that.

Comment: I can't ask questions more for **4** days, so can you please help me out

Comment: I'm really sorry, I couldn't figure it out. You have to go with the index.php#target-version for now.

Comment: As my all `divs` which are targeted have`hover` effect too. And if `hover` effect is ON, `target` effect is not working.

Comment: It should work. I tried it on the example I posted above and added this to the CSS: p:hover {
  background-color: green;
}

Comment: Your mouse was on div on which you targeted?

Comment: Can I have that link?

Comment: Where is the hover effect? I didn't find any hover there.

Comment: As mentionend, you still have to add this to the CSS: p:hover { background-color: green; }

Comment: Please Visit: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FL7I77PAZQ4W & try to click `click here`, after once, try more 3-4 times, and you will find what I am telling.